# Setting colors for specific bars that met a condition

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame in R

```
  SalesWeek         GS      IS         MM         MN        MN 
1          2       0.00  742340  3551557.4   384585.0   12044.64
2          3       0.00       0  1770886.0   685880.0       0.00
3          4       0.00       0  2720725.4   399797.9  391244.64
4          5       0.00       0 12301207.0   663900.0  122696.43
5          6       0.00       0  8973689.9  3031950.9   12044.64
6          7       0.00       0   264528.3        0.0  314984.64
7          8       0.00       0 11223543.6  1586324.0       0.00
8          9       0.00       0 18721800.9        0.0       0.00
9         10  309085.84       0 12494273.8  7893507.5       0.00
```

The data frame(weekarea) has other columns like "NL", "VS", and "SL". After setting up the data frame, I plotted them in a barplot

```
    ggplot(weekarea, aes(x=SalesWeek, y=NL))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::comma)+ 
  geom_vline(xintercept=12, color="red")+
  xlab("Weeks of the year")+
  ylab("Revenue in Pesos")
```

I wanted to color the bars corresponding to bars between weeks 11 and 22 so I figured to revise the first line above like this:

```
ggplot(weekarea, aes(x=SalesWeek, y=NL, fill=(SalesWeek>=12 && SalesWeek<22)))
```

Problem is it colored all bars. Can someone help me to set it up properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below approach:

```
library(ggplot2)

weekarea$pfill <- as.factor((weekarea$SalesWeek>=3 & weekarea$SalesWeek < 5)*1) ##Make a variable basis the conditional logic

###Use the pfill variable in the aes asthetics in ggplot2
ggplot(weekarea, aes(x=SalesWeek, y=MM,fill=pfill))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::comma)+ 
  geom_vline(xintercept=12, color="red")+
  xlab("Weeks of the year")+
  ylab("Revenue in Pesos")
```

Here we can see the color is different for week3 and week4

[image]

Comment: I tried it but the pfill column are all 0. I take it that means that everything is FALSE.

Comment: @Angelo Louise Lopez Use single "&" not "&&" when you are creating a pfill

Comment: @kpradeep OMG you are a life saver! I get now where I have gone wrong!

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is just to add an extra column to the data frame  specifying the color of the bars such as in this example:

```
library(ggplot2)
weekarea<-read.table(text="SalesWeek         GS      IS         MM         MN        MN 
    2       0.00  742340  3551557.4   384585.0   12044.64
    3       0.00       0  1770886.0   685880.0       0.00
    4       0.00       0  2720725.4   399797.9  391244.64
    5       0.00       0 12301207.0   663900.0  122696.43
    6       0.00       0  8973689.9  3031950.9   12044.64
    7       0.00       0   264528.3        0.0  314984.64
    8       0.00       0 11223543.6  1586324.0       0.00
    9       0.00       0 18721800.9        0.0       0.00
    10  309085.84       0 12494273.8  7893507.5       0.00", header=TRUE)

#add color specification:
weekarea$color=ifelse(weekarea$SalesWeek>5 & weekarea$SalesWeek<10, "red", "blue")

#add fill to aes
ggplot(weekarea, aes(x=SalesWeek, y=MM, fill= color))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::comma)+ 
  geom_vline(xintercept=12, color="red")+
  xlab("Weeks of the year")+
  ylab("Revenue in Pesos")
```